# Passar um valor em botão tipo link pela url para ser ultilizando em outra página com javascript ou php

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia a todos!
Sou novo em desenvolvimento web e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com Php, javascript e mysql. Minha duvida consiste na seguinte pergunta: Tenho uma tabela, onde estou carregando as informações que recuperei do meu banco de dados, e estão sendo exibidas como devem ser. O que eu preciso é, em uma das células, eu carrego o id da informação e ao clicar nele quero abrir uma outra aba, contendo as informações desse determinado id, o que eu não estou conseguindo fazer é passar esse id usando `<a href="minhapagina.php"></a>`. 
E a outra duvida seria, como eu pegar uma outra célula dessa mesma tabela e verificar se o valor nela é maior que zero, e se for, mudar o background.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: `<a href="minhapagina.php?minhavariavel=123"></a>` ?

Comment: Poste seu código PHP e o código HTML onde você popular os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de maneira bem simples no php:

```
<a href="minhapagina.php?foo=bar"></a>

<?php
    $foo = $_GET['foo']; // 'bar';
?>
```

Comment: Muito o brigado @jbrunoxd, funcionou direitinho! :D